# cakephp3 restrict controller use depending on user type

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am using cakephp3. I have a simple web application that has users. I have two user types, Admin and Standard. I want to limit Standard user to only view and index data. Whereas Admin type user should be able to add, edit, delete, view and index user data.

Basically, I want to globally restrict standard users, so that they cannot access the add, edit and delete methods of the controller.

So can anyone help me achieve it?

---

Below is /src/Controller/UsersController.php

```
            <?php
            namespace App\Controller;

            use App\Controller\AppController;

            /**
             * Users Controller
             *
             * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
             */
            class UsersController extends AppController
            {

                /**
                 * Index method
                 *
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function index()
                {
                    $this->paginate = [
                        'contain' => ['Countries', 'Cities', 'UserGroups', 'UserLevels']
                    ];
                    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
                    $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
                }

                public function dashboard()
                {

                }
                /**
                 * View method
                 *
                 * @param string|null $id User id.
                 * @return void
                 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
                 */
                public function view($id = null)
                {
                    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
                        'contain' => ['Countries', 'Cities', 'UserGroups', 'UserLevels', 'Alerts', 'DeviceLogs', 'Devices']
                    ]);
                    $this->set('user', $user);
                    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
                }

                /**
                 * Add method
                 *
                 * @return void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
                 */
                public function add()
                {
                    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
                    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
                        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                        } else {
                            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                        }
                    }
                    $countries = $this->Users->Countries->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $cities = $this->Users->Cities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $userGroups = $this->Users->UserGroups->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $userLevels = $this->Users->UserLevels->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $this->set(compact('user', 'countries', 'cities', 'userGroups', 'userLevels'));
                    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
                }

                /**
                 * Edit method
                 *
                 * @param string|null $id User id.
                 * @return void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
                 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
                 */
                public function edit($id = null)
                {
                    $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
                        'contain' => []
                    ]);
                    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
                        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
                        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                        } else {
                            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                        }
                    }
                    $countries = $this->Users->Countries->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $cities = $this->Users->Cities->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $userGroups = $this->Users->UserGroups->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $userLevels = $this->Users->UserLevels->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
                    $this->set(compact('user', 'countries', 'cities', 'userGroups', 'userLevels'));
                    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
                }

                /**
                 * Delete method
                 *
                 * @param string|null $id User id.
                 * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
                 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
                 */
                public function delete($id = null)
                {
                    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
                    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
                    if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
                        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
                    } else {
                        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
                    }
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                }

                public function login()
                {
                    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
                        if ($user) {
                            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
                        $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
                    }
                }

                public function logout()
                {
                    $this->Flash->success('You are now logged out.');
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
                }

                public function resetPassword() {

                }

                public function changepassword() {

                }

            }

            Below is AppController.php

            <?php

            namespace App\Controller;

            use Cake\Controller\Controller;
            use Cake\Event\Event;

            class AppController extends Controller
            {
                use \Crud\Controller\ControllerTrait;

                public $components = [
                    'RequestHandler',
                    'Crud.Crud' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            'Crud.Index',
                            'Crud.View',
                            'Crud.Add',
                            'Crud.Edit',
                            'Crud.Delete'
                        ],
                        'listeners' => [
                            'Crud.Api',
                            'Crud.ApiPagination',
                            'Crud.ApiQueryLog'
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
                /**
                 * Initialization hook method.
                 *
                 * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
                 *
                 * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
                 *
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function initialize()
                {
                    parent::initialize();

                    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
                    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
                    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                        'authenticate' => [
                            'Form' => [
                                'fields' => [
                                    'username' => 'email',
                                    'password' => 'password'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        'loginAction' => [
                            'controller' => 'Users',
                            'action' => 'login'
                        ],
                        // default is referer and in case of no referer loginRedirect (after login)
                        'loginRedirect' => [
                            'controller' => 'Users',
                            'action' => 'dashboard'
                        ],
                        'logoutRedirect' => '/',
                        'authError' => "Y"
                    ]);

                    // Allow the display action so our pages controller
                    // continues to work.
                    $this->Auth->allow(['resetPassword','add','changePassword','display']);
                }
                /**
                 * Before render callback.
                 *
                 * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event The beforeRender event.
                 * @return void
                 */
                public function beforeRender(Event $event)
                {
                    if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
                        in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
                    ) {
                        $this->set('_serialize', true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Regards,

Comment: Can you share your current attempt?

Comment: @Emacs I have no idea how to do it so I have just shared the code without restriction that does not limit user based on it's type. so can you please help me restricting user to specific controller method based on it's user type?

Comment: Or you can use [Tiny](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) if you don't want to mess with your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to use [ControllerAuthorize](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize).

As described in the docs, you have to add in `AppController` the following:

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null)
{
    // Any registered user can access public functions
    if (empty($this->request->params['prefix'])) {
        return true;
    }

    // Only admins can access admin functions
    if ($this->request->params['prefix'] === 'admin') {
        return (bool)($user['role'] === 'admin');
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

You then have to define admin as a valid key for [prefix routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing), and move your add, edit and delete actions to the new controller in

```
src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php
```